# Salesforce Pub/Sub client in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, salesforce, grpc, publish-subscribe

I would like to subscript to a Salesforce platform event.  I am trying to create a client in C#/.NET for a Salesforce Pub/Sub API.  There are examples in other languages but not in .NET : https://github.com/developerforce/pub-sub-api

I am using the Grpc.Net.Client nuget packages.

```
            var topicName = "/event/SomeEvent__e";
            var pubSubEndpoint = "https://api.pubsub.salesforce.com:7443";
            var accessToken = "xxxx";
            var organisationId = "xxxx";
            var instanceUrl = "https://xxxxx.sandbox.my.salesforce.com";

            var credentials = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((c, m) =>
            {
                m.Add("accesstoken", accessToken);
                m.Add("instanceurl", instanceUrl);
                m.Add("tenantid", organisationId);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });

            var options = new GrpcChannelOptions
            {
                Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), credentials)
            };

            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(pubSubEndpoint, options);
            var client = new PubSub.PubSubClient(channel);

            var topicRequest = new TopicRequest()
            {
                TopicName = topicName
            };
            var topic = client.GetTopic(topicRequest);
```

I know my credentials are correct because I can use postman to hit the oauth2 endpoint and get a valid access token.  But when I try and call a client method like client.GetTopic, then I get the following error.

*Status(StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="An error occurred while getting the metadata for org CORE/prod/00DN0000000c8Hk and topic /event/SomeEvent__e. Ensure the credentials and topic name are correct. rpcId: 21d854fb-17dc-4778-9524-6264bd1a920d")*

Am I setting up the credentials object wrong? I cannot find any example of subscribing to a Salesforce Pub/Sub in .NET.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: No I did not get it working. In the end, I gave up on using gRPC and followed this guide that uses the Bayeux protocol and CometD instead.  It makes uses of a package CometD.NetCore2.  Using this, I was able to subscribe to a channel and receive the Salesforce platform events.

https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/how-to-integrate-salesforce-streaming-api-with-net-core-application/

Comment: I have created a post on my blog with the information on how to subscribe to pub/sub api with .net, https://legiondevelopers.com/index.php/2023/02/05/connect-salesforce-pub-sub-api-with-net-part-ii/

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the tip. The only blocker I have is that I am unable to convert item.ReplayId to a string. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't forget that you could still also use outbound messages, and use an ASP.NET endpoint to receive the XML message.

Comment: @JuanPinzón: Error establishing a database connection